# How to pass token to server from android app

Tags: android, session-management

I am trying to authenticate my app with the server using token.

when I login to my system, server sends the token and I store it in current Session/ Application instance.

Later I need to pass that token on each request along with the other data.

Could anyone please provide me a way of sending the token to server? Do I need to do anything for security for eg. encryption etc. ?

Comment: thats completely depends on which service type u use?php?.net?

Comment: I am currently using java (Glassfish server)

Comment: i mean how will u send data from android to server? which server script hv u written? .php?

Comment: (Java) REST Client /  Using HttpClient object and content-type = Json (HttpPost)

Comment: actually i m basically question is url for example : myserver.com/index.php there in this rl i will post ..similarly i m asking the screipt used for posting data to server

Comment: oopps.. it's like http://server_ip:8080/app-client/customer

Comment: ok r u wrting server side script also?

Comment: Nop I am doing only the application side... but changes in server side is also possible..

Comment: ok but m still not getting satisfied answer from you to solve ur issue..hv u tried to post any kind of variable before with ur server?

Answer (score 1):

Pass your token in as `Auth Header` in your request header
for example

```
request.put("Auth","token_here");
```